# Не работает маска ввода телефона

Tags: javascript, jquery, inputmask

Не работает маска ввода телефона во всплывающем окне, само окно у меня формируется в js файле, и создается заново при вызове, если просто создать инпут на странице то всё работает отлично, но вот в окне не работает, как можно сделать чтобы маска заработала? Я так понимаю, что когда загружается страница скрипт работает один раз и устанавливает маску, как можно сделать чтобы скрипт срабатывал каждые 2 секунды, или по событию вызова окна?

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#tel").mask("+38(999) 999-9999");
});
```

Тут я создаю окно id добавил

```
openCart:function() {
            var b=0; a=c.getStorage(); g='<p class="jqcart-cart-title">\u041a\u043e\u0440\u0437\u0438\u043d\u0430 <span class="jqcart-print-order"></span></p><div class="jqcart-table-wrapper"><div class="jqcart-manage-order"><div class="jqcart-thead"><div class="jqcart-id">ID</div><div class="jqcart-img"></div><div>\u041d\u0430\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435</div><div>\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0430</div><div>\u041a\u043e\u043b-\u0432\u043e</div><div>\u0421\u0443\u043c\u043c\u0430</div><div></div></div>';

            var e; for(e in a)if(a.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
                var k=Math.ceil(a[e].count*a[e].price*100)/100; b=Math.ceil(100*(b+k))/100; g+='<div class="jqcart-tr" data-id="'+a[e].id+'">'; g+='<div class="jqcart-small-td">'+a[e].id+"</div>"; g+='<div class="jqcart-small-img jqcart-item-img"><img src="'+a[e].img+'" alt=""></div>'; g+='<div class="jqcart-title">'+a[e].title+"</div>"; g+='<div class="jqcart-price">'+a[e].price+"</div>"; g+='<div class="jqcart-count"><span class="jqcart-incr" data-incr="-1">&#8211;</span><input type="text" class="jqcart-amount" value="'+ a[e].count+'"><span class="jqcart-incr" data-incr="1">+</span></div>'; g+='<div class="jqcart-sum">'+k+" "+h.currency+"</div>"; g+='<div class="jqcart-small-deny"><span class="jqcart-del-item"></span></div>'; g+="</div>"
            }

            // <div class="jqcart-grid"><p><label>\u0424\u0418\u041e:</label><input type="text" name="user_name"></p><p><label>\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d:</label><input type="text" name="user_phone"></p><p><label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="user_mail"></p><p><label>\u0410\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441:</label><input type="text" name="user_address"></p></div>

            g+="</div></div>"; g+='<div class="jqcart-subtotal">\u0418\u0442\u043e\u0433\u043e: <strong>'+b+"</strong> "+h.currency+"</div>"; b=b?g+'<p class="jqcart-cart-title">\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0430\u043a\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0438\u043d\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f:</p><form class="jqcart-orderform" action="zakaz.php" method="post"><div class="jqcart-grid"><p><label>\u0424\u0418\u041e:</label><input type="text" name="user_name"></p><p><label>\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d:</label><input type="text" id="tel" name="user_phone"></p><p><label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="user_mail"></p><p><label>\u0410\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441:</label><input type="text" name="user_address"></p></div><div class="jqcart-text"><label>\u041a\u043e\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0438\u0439:</label><textarea class="jqcart-textarea" name="user_comment"></textarea></div> <p class="jqcart-submit-btn"><input type="submit" value="\u041e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c \u0437\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437"><input type="reset" value="\u0412\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0443\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f \u043a \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043f\u043a\u0430\u043c"></p> </form> ': '<h2 class="jqcart-empty-cart">\u041a\u043e\u0440\u0437\u0438\u043d\u0430 \u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u0430</h2><center><form class="jqcart-orderform"><p class="jqcart-submit-btn"><input type="reset" style="margin:0 auto;" value="\u0412\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0443\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f \u043a \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043f\u043a\u0430\u043c"></p></form></center>'; d('<div class="jqcart-layout"><div class="jqcart-checkout">123</div></div>').appendTo("body").find(".jqcart-checkout").html(b)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а что мешает просто после

```
g+="</div></div>"; g+='<div class="jqcart-subtotal">\u0418\u0442\u043e\u0433\u043e: <strong>'+b+"</strong> "+h.currency+"</div>"; b=b?g+'<p class="jqcart-cart-title">\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0430\u043a\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0438\u043d\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f:</p><form class="jqcart-orderform" action="zakaz.php" method="post"><div class="jqcart-grid"><p><label>\u0424\u0418\u041e:</label><input type="text" name="user_name"></p><p><label>\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d:</label><input type="text" id="tel" name="user_phone"></p><p><label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="user_mail"></p><p><label>\u0410\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441:</label><input type="text" name="user_address"></p></div><div class="jqcart-text"><label>\u041a\u043e\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0438\u0439:</label><textarea class="jqcart-textarea" name="user_comment"></textarea></div> <p class="jqcart-submit-btn"><input type="submit" value="\u041e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c \u0437\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437"><input type="reset" value="\u0412\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0443\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f \u043a \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043f\u043a\u0430\u043c"></p> </form> ': '<h2 class="jqcart-empty-cart">\u041a\u043e\u0440\u0437\u0438\u043d\u0430 \u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u0430</h2><center><form class="jqcart-orderform"><p class="jqcart-submit-btn"><input type="reset" style="margin:0 auto;" value="\u0412\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0443\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f \u043a \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043f\u043a\u0430\u043c"></p></form></center>'; d('<div class="jqcart-layout"><div class="jqcart-checkout">123</div></div>').appendTo("body").find(".jqcart-checkout").html(b);
```

вызвать

```
$("#tel").mask("+38(999) 999-9999");
```

перед закрывающей фигурной скобкой "}" окончания функции openCart:function

если вызвать его после того как вы прикрепили html в dom все будет работать